# put a button next to the other ionic3

Tags: css, ionic-framework, ionic3

[image: pls check image here]

I wanted to put a button on the side of the other, not one underneath the other

```
<ion-row>
                  <span   *ngIf="dado.status == 0" style="margin-left: 50%">
                  Pendende
                </span>      
                 <span   *ngIf="dado.status == 0" 
          style="background-color: #d9534f; margin-left: 50%;">
                  x Cancelar
                </span> 


    </ion-row>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try it without  `style="margin-left: 50%"`. You are adding 50% margin on the left side of the button, which is half of the screen. Obviously two buttons with 50% margin each cannot fit next to each other. You can also add `display: inline-block;`

```
<ion-row>
    <span   *ngIf="dado.status == 0" style="display: inline-block;">
              Pendende
    </span>      
    <span   *ngIf="dado.status == 0" style="background-color: #d9534f;
             display: inline-block;">
              x Cancelar
    </span> 


</ion-row>
```

**Tip**: If you run it in a browser, like chrome, you can right click on each item, and select `inspect`. There, you can add/remove styles on the fly and see the results. The most helpful part of it is the tab named "computed" where you can see the margins and padding for each item.

https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/inspect-styles/